# Superman comic with Green genie/Ming-like villain

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I remember a silver age, more or less comic book where a villian named Urko or something tried to take over the fortress of solitude.  He may have been a sort of a supernatural beings.

the lower part of the character looked like the lower part of a genie or ghost in popular culture.

[image]

And his upper part looked sort of like Ming the Merciless.

[image]

And he was green all over.

So does anyone remember anything about that story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Urko the Terrible" appeared as a one-off villain in [Superman #187](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_187)

[image]

Comment: I mean, yes, correct answer, but... where the hell is Supes getting the air for this super-breath?!

Comment: QValorum - A very fast answer.  But I have often been annoyed by answers to other persons' comic book questions giving just the title and the issue number, expecting everyone to be able to calculate the date from that.  If you hadn't provided a link to find that Superman # 187 was dated June 1966 I would have been annoyed. So Urko looks 800,000 miles tall in that panel!

Comment: @Tim - And Urko looks about 800,000 miles tall in that panel!

Comment: @M.A.Golding - It's just good practice to link to either DC Wikia or ComicVine.

Comment: @Valorum - I have seen a lot of comic book answers that give the issue number.  And I am not sure that the persons who answer always gave links to more information like you did.  I'm sure that sometimes the persons who ask the questions have no way of knowing whether the issue number was during the Golden Age of Comics, the Silver Age, the Molybdenum Age,  the Iridium Age, or some other age.  So I would have been annoyed if you hadn't given the link where I could find the date.

Comment: Oops!  I forgot to accept the answer until now..

Comment: @M.A.Golding - That's....wait for it..... TERRIBLE of you!

Comment: Urko - the love child of Orko from HE-MAN, and Steve Urkel?