# Does Batman have a spacesuit?

Tags: dc, batman

Batman has different types of suits and various gadgets for his fights. But does he have a spacesuit for surviving in space? If so, in which edition is the use of a spacesuit by Batman shown in DC comics?

Comment: This question has been asked so often over the years that it's a [common trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BatmanCanBreatheInSpace).  (Warning: TVTropes).  There was also [this](https://www.shortpacked.com/comic/batman-can-breathe-in-space) that was memed everywhere for a while.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Why does TVTropes need a warning?

Comment: @Prometheus [What is so wrong about TvTropes?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6396/98028)

Comment: The answer is obviously yes...but the question should be what does he call it ? Bat Space Suit ? Or Space Bat Suit ?

Comment: @user96551 interesting thought , would love to know the answer to this question as well

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### He has at least nine (and an unclear one, and a bonus one).

*Ordered by media and publication date.*

#### Seven in the comics

- One shown in [tilley31's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/232307/98028) (1969).
- The unclear one would be the spacesuit he wore in *Justice League of America* #202 (1982). It looks like a regular space suit, but it has a Bat-Symbol on it and what looks like a utility belt which, at the very least, contains tools to repair the JLA satellite. There's not enough material to state it was made by Batman, and the comic only vaguely refers to it as "Batman's spacesuit":

  [image: Hawkman watching as Batman drifts into space]
- One worn in *Batman/Superman* #64 (2009), while Batman was "casually" inspecting a shipwreck in space. Despite the red symbol, it has nothing to do with Batman Beyond.

  [image: Batman exiting his Bat-spaceship in a Bat-spacesuit]
- One worn by Dick Grayson (who was going around by "Batman" at that time) in *Justice League of America* #55 (2011):

  [image: Supergirl being worried Batman/Dick Grayson died in space, but it turned out he had a spacesuit]
- Another shown in *Batman/Superman* #28 (2015); by the way Alfred words it, the thing was certainly built by Batman.

  > SUPERMAN: There's something you... There's something *Batman* needs to see.
  > ALFRED: I'll prepare your suit, sir.
  > BATMAN: I'm guessing, Alfred, given recent events, whatever​ Superman wants to show me is on the Moon.
  > ALFRED: I'll prepare your *other* suit, sir.

  [image: Batman prepares to suit up for the Moon]

  [image: Batman on the Moon in his spacesuit, Superman in the background]
- Another shown in *DC Cybernetic Summer* (2020). Destroyed along with Brother Eye's drones in a satellite explosion.

  [image: Batman in a spacesuit hacked by Brother Eye]
- Another very briefly shown in *Detective Comics* #1027 (2020), used to fight against Brainiac.

  [image: Batman, Martian Manhunter, Cyborg, and Hawkgirl fighting Brainiac]

#### One LEGO Batman Space Batsuit

The impressive [Bat-Space shuttle building kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075KZNHQL), set in *The LEGO Batman Movie* universe, features a "Space Batsuit":

[image: Several Bat-family LEGO minifigures, including the Space Batsuit]

#### One in *Batman: The Brave and the Bold*

Seen in the very first episode, "The Rise of the Blue Beetle" (2008): a seemingly regular Batman suit, combined with a breathing thingy and a jetpack. I don't know if that counts as a *space suit*, but he's flying in outer space and not dying. I don't think kevlar and leather allow for that.

[image: Batman and Blue Beetle in space, a space station of sorts is seen in the background]

#### One in *LEGO Batman 3: Beyond Gotham*

The minifigure sold by LEGO [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00R8JQMU8) is listed as "Space Batman". Batman can be seen in action wearing this suit in [various videos of the game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DETQbD0zGCA).

[image: Space Batman. Surprisingly light grey]

#### Bonus

As a bonus, here's a Batman spacesuit which is *supposedly* not a Batman spacesuit. It's featured in *Superman/Batman* #78 (2011), where two kids imagine how a "Batman vs Superman" scenario would play out. Part of it involves Superman taking Batman to space, and [Batman revealing his suit actually contains an unfolding spacesuit inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szMjM.jpg). And while it may just be a kid's imagination, at the end of the issue, Batman (who was watching from above) tells Superman that the kid had "a lot of it right, how I'd beat you". [Without detailing exactly what...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRrmj.jpg)

[image: Batman and Superman fight in outer space]

#### End note: because he's Batman

Standard comic rules apply to the whole DC universe, and Batman adds another layer to that. If the writer decides his regular suit + breathing device is enough to last him two whole minutes in outer space, then it will be, as shown in *Legends of the Dark Knight* #2 (2011). Because he's Batman!

[image: Batman in outer space (again), describing how he hates space, and losing his JLA signal device]

<sub>Hat tip to [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) for locating that panel's issue for me!</sub>

Comment: I've been compiling this list for three hours and I'm still finding new ones. Just how many spacesuits does this guy need?

Comment: That last one is in the same ballpark as the [Space Activity Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_counterpressure_suit) which only has a pressurized helmet.

Comment: Is Superman wearing... some sort of mask in *Batman/Superman #28*?

Comment: I’m sure that I’ve seen others back in the 70s and 80s.

Comment: Interesting, that bonus one looks remarkably like the Black Panther suit

Comment: @Jenayah great compilation but Batman is Batman he can beat any tech giant in innovation 

Comment: @detly related reading: [Does Superman need to breathe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34440/98028). TLDR it's inconsistent throughout the years, but we can assume that in this case the mask is there for him to be able to communicate with Batman

Comment: Are some of the spacesuits only for very short-term survivability instead of extended spacewalks? (note the complete lack of an oxygen tank on many of the suits, which means they can be used only for a few minutes)

Comment: "I don't think kevlar and leather allow for that." don't tell Virgin Galactic that, their suit is aramid fibre (of which kevlar is one brand name) and has some leather components in the footwear.

Answer (score 25):

Yes.

*Detective Comics* #388 - Public Luna-Tic Number One! ; Surprise! This'll Kill You!

Fittingly released one month before the first moon landing in 1969. Joker sends Batman and Robin to "be the first to die on the moon".

[image: Batman and Robin find themselves on the moon in spacesuits; a voice comes from the side (Joker) telling them that they are on the moon]

Comment: I would like to know about a spacesuit built by Batman for himself

Comment: Well, the comic doesn't clarify that but the suits have the Batman logo and Robin logo. Also if Joker sent them there "to die", I'd think he wouldn't go through the trouble of making space suits for them. My point is, the comic doesn't spell it out but it seems clear the suits were built by Batman...maybe Alfred helped?

Comment: Batman doesn't need a space suit: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c9/99/2d/c9992dca74e676bb425a0002d314ae75.png

Comment: @tilley31 In the comic, Batman and Robin are knocked out by The Joker's goons. They wake up dressed like that. As far as I can tell, Joker provided the suits, because Batman didn't have one in the previous scene. Joker making Bat-themed space suits makes as much sense as anything else in his plan to use an anti-gravity device to trick Batman into thinking he is on the moon.

Comment: The grammar and stuff used in the caption looks pretty rough.  I'm surprised they didn't go back and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie *JLA Adventures: Trapped in Time*, Batman and Robin both use spacesuits. It can be seen in the video below

[image]